# Java Networking Client Applet

Tags: java, http, applet, port

Sorry if this is a stupid question. I was following the 'Networking Client Applet Example' found at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/clientExample.html. However, I am having trouble figuring out how to implement step 7:

*7. Open the web page containing your applet in a browser by entering the URL of the web page. The host name in the URL should be the same as the name of the host on which the server-side application is running.

For example, if the server-side application is running on a machine named JohnDoeMachine, you should enter a similar URL. The exact port number and path will vary depending on your web server setup.

"http://JohnDoeMachine:8080/quoteApplet/quoteApplet.html"

The QuoteClientApplet will be displayed on the web page.*

We are asked to open the web page containing the applet by entering the URL of the web page. I understand where quoteApplet comes from, but how am I supposed to find out the http address and port number of the web page? It says that the port number and path will vary depending on my web server setup. How do I set it up? Do I have to use a host web server like apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they're asking you put the files on a web server somewhere. If you have a hosting account, you could upload it there. Otherwise, you could install a web server like apache on your own computer(recommended for testing).

Each web server has different install instructions, but generally you install it and have it listen on port 80, which is probably the default config for most web servers. They're example assumed you have the webserver listen on port 8080

If you have the webserver listen on port 80, then url to use in your browser would be something like
http://`localhost`/quoteApplet/quoteApplet.html

You can omit the port in the url if its port 80. `localhost` is a special address that always points back to your own computer.

The reason they ask you to install a web server has to do with javas security model - if you use a browser to load the web page from the filesystem instead of from a url, java wont let you open socket connections to other domains unless you edit the java policy file - and this gets more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

It says right on that page:

> 2 . Include the following HTML code in a web page to deploy QuoteClientApplet.

```javascript
 <script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
 <script> 
    var attributes =
      { code:'QuoteClientApplet.class',  width:500, height:100} ; 
    var parameters =
      {codebase_lookup:'true'};
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.6'); 
</script>
```

You can host that web page in any webserver you like, this applet will run in the browser, not serverside.

Comment: +1, but note that `code:'QuoteClientApplet.class'` should be `code:'QuoteClientApplet'`.  The former is tolerated as opposed to correct.